# Point group of a disjoint union of graphs

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph.

$\Gamma(G)$ is the point group og $G$, i.e. the automorphism group of $G$.

Suppose $$G \cong  nH $$ i.e. the disjoint union of $n$ graphs isomorphic to $H$. Then what is $\Gamma(G)$ ?

Comment: If $H$ is connected (or more generally if no two of the connected components of $H$ are isomorphic) then $\Gamma(G) = \Gamma(H) \wr S_n$. Otherwise, it is a more complicated direct product of wreath products.

Comment: @DerekHolt: What is the set used for the wreath product ? Is $$ \Omega = \lbrace 1,2, \ldots n \rbrace $$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ be a connected graph and let $G$ consist of $n$ copies of $H$.  The point group $\Gamma(G)$ contains elements that map each copy of $H$ to itself.  Thus, the $n$-fold direct product $\Gamma(H)^n$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma(G)$.  Also, the different copies of $H$ can be permuted amongst themselves, giving another $n!$ automorphisms $S_n$. These two subgroups together generate a group called the wreath product $\Gamma(H) Wr S_n = \Gamma(H)^n \rtimes S_n$. Thus the graph $nH$ has $n! |\Gamma(H)|^n$ automorphisms.